# Magento2 Price filters

Tags: magento2

We have added price filters in layered navigation section its working fine in the test site, but not working properly in live.

What is the issue exactly? I am unable to find.

Comment: Check error log in var/log folder

Comment: Hi @nikunj iam getting like this in var/log section:[2018-06-06 13:43:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.bottom.container' tries to reorder itself towards 'main.content', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'wrapper.main.content' respectively. [] []

Comment: it is not related to your issue check major error if any

Comment: other than that not getting any major issues

Comment: Hi @Nikunj prices are filtering. but we have special price products with lower prices but its not displaying the products in magento2